# PHP use GET values from URL to use in a function

Tags: php, function, get

I'm trying to change some php code so that i get my values from the URL and use them in my converter function. I keep getting "object not found" when i try it on the URL like so......

https://localhost/atwd/test/white%20hat/conv?amnt=10&from=GBP&to=USD

Following is my `CurrencyConverter.php` file

```
<?php
class CurrencyConverter    
{
    var $xml_file = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
    var $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db, $mysql_table;
    var $exchange_rates = array();

    // Load Currency Rates

    function CurrencyConverter($host, $user, $pass, $db, $tb)
    {
        $this->mysql_host = $host;
        this->mysql_user = $user;
        $this->mysql_pass = $pass;
        $this->mysql_db = $db;
        $this->mysql_table = $tb;

        $this->checkLastUpdated();

        $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
        $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db, $conn);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->mysql_table;
        $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            $this->exchange_rates[$row['currency']] = $row['rate'];
        }
    }

    /* Perform the actual conversion, defaults to £1.00 GBP to USD */
    function convert($a, $b, $c, $decimals = 2)
    {
        $a = $_GET['amnt'];
        $b = $_GET['from'];
        $c = $_GET['to'];

        strip_tags($a);
        strip_tags($b);
        strip_tags($c);

        return (number_format(($a / $this->exchange_rates[$b]) * $this->exchange_rates[$c], $decimals));
    }

    /* Check to see how long since the data was last updated */
    function checkLastUpdated()
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
        $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db, $conn);
        $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM " . $this->mysql_db . " LIKE '" . $this->mysql_table . "'";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0)
        {
            $this->createTable();
        }
        else
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
            if (time() > (strtotime($row["Update_time"]) + (12 * 60 * 60)))
            {
                $this->downloadExchangeRates();
            }
        }
    }

    /* Download xml file, extract exchange rates and store values in database */
    function downloadExchangeRates()
    {
        $currency_domain = substr($this->xml_file, 0, strpos($this->xml_file, "/"));
        $currency_file = substr($this->xml_file, strpos($this->xml_file, "/"));
        $fp = @fsockopen($currency_domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
        if ($fp)
        {
            $out = "GET " . $currency_file . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $out.= "Host: " . $currency_domain . "\r\n";
            $out.= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8)      Gecko/20051111 Firefox/1.5\r\n";
            $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            fwrite($fp, $out);
            while (!feof($fp))
            {
                $buffer = fgets($fp, 128);
            }

            fclose($fp);
            $pattern = "{<Cube\s*currency='(\w*)'\s*rate='([\d\.]*)'/>}is";
            preg_match_all($pattern, $buffer, $xml_rates);
            array_shift($xml_rates);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml_rates[0]); $i++)
            {
                $exchange_rate[$xml_rates[0][$i]] = $xml_rates[1][$i];
            }

            $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
            $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db, $conn);
            foreach($exchange_rate as $currency => $rate)
            {
                if ((is_numeric($rate)) && ($rate != 0))
                {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->mysql_table . " WHERE currency='" . $currency . "'";
                    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                    if (mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
                    {
                        $sql = "UPDATE " . $this->mysql_table . " SET rate=" . $rate . " WHERE currency='" . $currency . "'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->mysql_table . " VALUES('" . $currency . "'," . $rate . ")";
                    }

                    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Create the currency exchange table */
    function createTable()
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
        $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db, $conn);
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $this->mysql_table . " ( currency char(3) NOT NULL default '',  rate float NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY(currency) ) ENGINE=MyISAM";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->mysql_table . " VALUES('EUR',1)";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        $this->downloadExchangeRates();
    }
}
```

and here is where im calling the function from a different file called `conv.php`.

```
 <?php
     include 'CurrencyConverter.php';

     $x = new CurrencyConverter('localhost','root','','converterTest','currency');   

     echo $x->convert($a, $b, $c);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, why have parameters if you are immediately discarding them in favour of getting url params.  Secondly, please tag homework as such.  Thirdly, post the full code your are using - not just a snippet that you think is the cause, as it may not be.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_GET['amn']);` to see if the problem comes from here?

Comment: Well your url isn't specifying a php file, so you're using a rewrite rule? Can you post the **exact** error message please.

Comment: Ok i have provided the whole file code.
exchange_rates is a column in my database.
And the exact error message is when i type the URL as so......
https://localhost/atwd/test/white%20hat/conv.php?amnt=10&from=GBP&to=USD

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: exchange_rate in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\CurrencyConverter.php on line 106

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\CurrencyConverter.php on line 106

Notice: Undefined variable: a in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\conv.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: b in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\conv.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: c in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\conv.php on line 6
15.67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'convert' function is in your main file, it could be the missing file ending in the url:

https://localhost/atwd/test/white%20hat/conv.php?amnt=10&from=GBP&to=USD

If the 'convert' function is in the 'CurrencyConverter.php' file you can try to include it with parameters:

```
include('CurrencyConverter.php?foo=1&bar=2');
```

**EDIT:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: exchange_rate in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\CurrencyConverter.php on line 106

--> On line  99 you are defining `$exchange_rate[$xml_rates[0][$i]]` and not `$exchange_rate`
this is not the same and causes an error.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\CurrencyConverter.php on line 106

--> This seems to be an aftereffect of the undefined variable $exchange_rate

> Notice: Undefined variable: a in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white
>   hat\conv.php on line 6     Notice: Undefined variable: b in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\conv.php on line 6     Notice:
>   Undefined variable: c in C:\xampp\htdocs\atwd\test\white hat\conv.php
>   on line 6

--> Here is the mistake i think. You try to call the function `convert()` form 'CurrencyConverter.php' but the Variables `$a`, `$b` and `$c` get defined in the function itself. So the variables are not defined in 'conv.php' and the call of `convert()` yet.
I would suggest that you try to $_GET the values of the url and define the variable in the call of the function at the same time.

```
convert($_GET['amnt'], $_GET['from'], $_GET['to'])
```

Like this you have the variables already defined in your CurrencyConverter.php and you can delete line 41 to 43.